# Spring Boot upgrade to 2.2.5 causing required request part 'file' is not present

Tags: spring-boot, servlet-filters

So we upgraded our Spring Boot from 2.0.3 to 2.2.5 and this caused our file import to start failing. 
 So my code is like this:

```
public Result<FileResponse> importFile(@RequestParam(value = "file") MultipartFile file) {...}
```

We have a couple custom filters and we run on embedded Tomcat 9.0.3.  We get a response similar to `...required request part 'file' is not present...` with a stacktrace.  Looks like the file is not getting populated properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what happened is:

1. Spring Boot 2.0.3 has certain filters
2. HiddenHttpProcessor filter ran the code `request.getParts()`.
3. So running this actually causes Spring to perform magic where spring reads from the input stream, parses the request parts, populates the request parts, removes the request parts from stream, and then Spring acts like the stream was never read from.
4. Spring Boot's upgrade to 2.2.5 caused a change in which filters run.  So `request.getParts()` was never ran before our custom filters ran.
5. One of our custom filters was wrapping the request.  During the creation of the wrapped request, we ran `IOUtils.copy(this.request.getInputStream(),baos)` which copied our `request.getInputStream()` to `ByteArrayOutputStream`.  **This was to get around Spring's rule that calling `request.getInputStream()` is only allowed once.**
6. For some reason, converting `request.getInputStream()` to any kind of byte array changes the stream to the point that it cannot be parsed properly by `request.getParts()`.
7. So you have to call `request.getParts()` before manipulating the `request.getInputStream()`.

This is kind of a bit of conflict between Spring InputStream magic and normal servlet filter patterns.  Spring treats their internals differently then how outsiders call their code.  Because technically `request.getParts()` should NOT be allowed to manipulate the stream by Spring's own rules.